# The named parameter isn't defined. Error in Flutter project because of upgrade version

Tags: flutter, dart, upgrade, beta

ERROR:-

1. The named parameter 'favoriteItemsAlignment' isn't defined.
2. The named parameter 'mode' isn't defined.
3. The named parameter 'dropdownSearchDecoration' isn't defined.
4. The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic Function(dynamic)>'.

```
Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 45,
                        child: DropdownSearch(
                          favoriteItemsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, //1. error
                          mode: Mode.DIALOG,  //2. error
                          dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration( //3. error
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: dropdownCityName,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                          ),
                          items: dropdownItems, //4. error
                          onChanged: dropdownOnChangeds,
                          selectedItem: dropdownSelectedItems,
                          // selectedItem: dropdownSelectedItems,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

hey I got this error because i upgrade flutter stable to beta version.
than reverse the version again but error is not resolve.

Comment: which version of dropdown_search do you use?

Comment: dropdown_search: ^5.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the API of version 3.0.1. Downgrade the library or migrate the code to version 5.0.1

It should look like this:

```
Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: 45,
        child: DropdownSearch(
          // Instead of this
          //
          // favoriteItemsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          // mode: Mode.DIALOG,
          //
          // add this
          popupProps: const PopupProps.dialog(
            favoriteItemProps: FavoriteItemProps(favoriteItemsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center),
          ),

          // Instead of this
          //
          // dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
          //   disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          //   hintText: dropdownCityName,
          //   hintStyle: TextStyle(
          //     color: Colors.black,
          //     fontSize: 12,
          //   ),
          // ),
          //
          // add this
          dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
            dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
              disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: dropdownCityName,
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          items: dropdownItems,
          onChanged: dropdownOnChangeds,
          selectedItem: dropdownSelectedItems,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Regarding the error #4 - you're passing a list of wrong objects (your list contains functions). Could you please say what `dropdownItems` is? How you define it?

Comment: Error #4 :-   final List<Object>? dropdownItems;

Comment: how do you assign the value?

Comment: 1. /// Trying this but is not working.
 List<SelectCitieData>? _selectCitieData = [];

 itemAsString: _selectCitieData?.map((city) {
                                  return city.cityName ?? "";
                                }).toList(),  
=======================
2.class NavigationDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  NavigationDrawer({
    Key? key,
    required this.listLength,
    this.dropdownItems,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Object>? dropdownItems;

///and in dropdown we use like this:-

 items: dropdownItems,

Comment: try `final List<String> dropdownItems = []` instead of `final List<Object>? dropdownItems`